# SAPUI5 PlanningCalendar - get EndDate by startDateChange event

Tags: sapui5

I want to find out the end date of the planning calender every time the user changes the displayed period. I tried to use the [startDateChange](http://API%20Reference:%20https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PlanningCalendar/events/startDateChange) event offered by the PlanningCalender class. In the API reference it's only described how to get the start date (using sap.m.PlanningCalendar#getStartDate()). Can I maybe access the end date by the parameters (like for the intervalSelect event).

What else can I try to access the end date of the calender every time the user changes the displayed period?